# Как правильно составить linq запрос из бд?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

Пытаюсь правильно составить запрос.
Запрос должен группировать по ApplicationUserId. А дальше получить первый объект и вернуть вместе с пользователем.

```
(from trainings in dbContext.TrainingObjects
 group trainings by trainings.ApplicationUserId into groups
 let bTr = groups.OrderByDescending(a => a.Index).First()
 let user = dbContext.Users.First(a => a.Id == groups.Key)
 select new
 {
     tr = bTr,
     user = user
 }).ToList()
```

Но вылазит ошибка:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Processing of the LINQ expression '(GroupByShaperExpression:
> KeySelector: (t.ApplicationUserId),
> ElementSelector:(EntityShaperExpression:
> EntityType: TrainingObject
> ValueBufferExpression:
> (ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember)
> IsNullable: False
> )
> )'

```
public class TrainingObject
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore, IgnoreDataMember, ForeignKey("ApplicationUserId")]
    public UserDetails UserDetails { get; set; }
    public double Index { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class UserDetails
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ApplicationUserId")]
    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TrainingObject> TrainingObjects { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Попробовал в один  запрос, но не дает сделать упорядочивание

```
(from trs in dbContext.TrainingObjects
 join user in dbContext.UsersDetails on trs.ApplicationUserId equals user.Id
 group trs by trs.ApplicationUserId into grTrs 
 select new
 {
     trs = grTrs.OrderByDescending(q=>q.Index).First(),
     user = grTrs.First().UserDetails
 }).ToList();
```

> OrderByDescending(q => q.Index)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either

Comment: Что именно должен делать этот запрос? Или надо по неработающему запросу догадаться?

Comment: @aepot, запрос должен группировать, по ApplicationUserId
А дальше получить. первый объект и вернуть вместе с пользователем

Comment: Вы решили проблему? Если да, напишите ответ. Если нет, опубликуйте код определения контекста со связями. И укажите версию EF.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, Не решил. EF - 3.1.5

Comment: Здесь в коде записаны два запроса к базе. EF естественно, не может превратить их в один. Надо либо в явном виде посылать два запроса (выбрать первый тренинг, затем загрузить соответствующего пользователя), либо переписать сам запрос. В SQL, если бы делали это одним запросом, вы бы сначала соединили (join) таблицы тренингов и пользователей, затем бы их сгруппировали (group by), сортировали (order by) и, наконец, брали бы верхнюю строку (top 1). Точно также надо писать и LINQ.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko, Я понимаю, что нужно сделать. И сделал, тоже самое в LINQ при загруженных данных, имею ввиду не в БД. А когда пишется запрос именно для бд. То чуток сложнее и не получается. Я вот написал записал запрос. Но он не работает

Answer (score 1):

Для LINQ to Entities, существует пока нерушимое ограничение - после `group by` можно доставать только ключ группировки или результат агрегации. В вашем же случае вы хотите получить целый объект.

Это обусловлено ограничением самого SQL. Если вам нужен такой запрос, необходимо использовать чистый SQL и оконные функции. Оконные функции не поддерживаются реализацией EF любых версий.

Но, на всякий случай, оставлю вариант с использованием расширения для EF Core https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore - используйте версию 3.X

Расширение использует транслятор LINQ от linq2db и не имеет ограничений присущих EF Core.
Заранее предупреждаю, я создатель этого расширения.

```cs
var rnQuery = 
   from t in dbContext.TrainingObjects
   select new
   {
       RN = Sql.Ext.RowNumber().Over()
          .PartitionBy(t.ApplicationUserId)
          .OrderByDesc(t.Index)
          .ToValue(),
       tr = t,
       user = t.UserDetails.ApplicationUser
  };

var resultQuery = 
   from q in rnQuery
   where q.RN == 1
   select new
   {
       q.tr,
       q.user
   };

var result = resultQuery
   .ToLinqToDB()
   .ToList();
```

Comment: Это будет работать на MySql? Автор использует именно эту СУБД.

Comment: Да, будет,  если версия MySQL >= 8

Comment: Тут детально о поддержке https://linq2db.github.io/articles/sql/Window-Functions-(Analytic-Functions).html#engines-that-support-window-functions

Comment: Замечательно! Я сам пользуюсь этими функциями, но только на Sql Server. Не был уверен насчёт MySql.

Comment: Да как бы стало стандартом. Если база не поддерживает, я бы задумался нужно ли на нее переходить.